# Null Pointer Exception when calling onCreateOptionsMenu()

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the following error,

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference
```

on this code:

```
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

}
```

I can't figure out how to fix it - does anyone have any suggestions? I understand what a nullpointer exception is, but I don't understand why searchView is null.

Comment: this is saying that `searchView` is null.

Comment: Hi @ScaryWombat - I understand that. I know what a null pointer exception is, but I don't know why searchView is null.

Comment: If problem persists after changing 

    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

to

    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
and none of other solutions working then problem may be in your enabled proguard. so I use 

    -keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
in my proguard-rules.pro file and its working perfectly.